# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' with @ notation and no xml files

Tags: spring, hibernate, javabeans, entitymanager

I know that this question has been answered many times on SO but in this case i preferred to use @ notation over actual xml files to configure a hibernate database.

firstly here the error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
at web_application.Application.main(Application.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javax.persistence.Lob, at table: testruns, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(result_files)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1736)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Here is where i configure my hibernate setup

```
package web_application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

@Autowired
private static Environment env;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperties().getProperty(
            "jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperties().getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperties().getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperties().getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "web_application" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperties()
                    .getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperties()
                    .getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Object[] sources = { Application.class, NightlySchedule.class };
    SpringApplication.run(sources, args);

}
}
```

This is where the Entity manager is actually being used

```
package web_application;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTRUNS")
public class RunEntity {
private int ID;
private int testNumber;
private String testName;
private String environment;
private String source;
private String passOrFail;
private Timestamp date;
private Lob resultFiles;


@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue
public int getID()
{
    return this.ID;
}
@Column(name="TestNumber")
public int getTestNumber()
{
    return this.testNumber;
}
public void setTestNumber(int testNum){this.testNumber = testNum;}

@Column(name="TestName")
public String testName()
{
    return this.testName;
}
public void setTestName(String testName){this.testName = testName;}

@Column(name="Environment")
public String getEnvironment()
{
    return this.environment;
}
public void setEnvironment(String enviro){this.environment = enviro;}

@Column(name="Source")
public String getSource()
{
    return this.source;
}
public void setSource(String src){this.source = src;}

@Column(name="PassOrFail")
public String getPassOrFail()
{
    return this.passOrFail;
}
public void setPassOrFail(String pOrF){this.passOrFail = pOrF;}

@Column(name="Date")
public Timestamp getDate()
{
    return this.date;
}
public void setDate(Timestamp dates){this.date = dates;}

@Column(name="ResultFiles")
public Lob getResultFiles()
{
    return this.resultFiles;
}
public void setResultFiles(Lob file){this.resultFiles = file;}

}
```

and here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.3.RELEASE")


}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


ext.hibernateVersion='4.1.5.SP1'
ext.hibernateValidatorVersion='4.3.0.Final'

 jar {
baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
mavenRepo url: 'http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/'
mavenRepo url: 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'


}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.4.1.201406201815-r'
compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE'
compile("com.h2database:h2")

compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1"
compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.2.2'

compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.12'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.6.12'   

compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hibernateVersion"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"    
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidatorVersion"
compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"


testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Comment: Where are the getters and setters for RunEntity class?

Comment: I was going to add those one i figured this issue out.  Do you think that that could be the issue?

Comment: Add and check what happens.

Comment: No dice,  same exact error